# Wildcard a route to error controller in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404, wildcard

I want to wildcard a route in Laravel 5 and maybe do something like:

```
Route::any('(.*)', 'ErrorController@index');
```

But I can't seem to get that to work. Seems like an issue others are having. Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I've found one workaround, but there has got to be a better solution.

```
Route::get('/{one}', 'ErrorController@index');
Route::get('/{one}/{two}', 'ErrorController@index'); 
Route::get('/{one}/{two}/{three}', 'ErrorController@index'); 
Route::get('/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}', 'ErrorController@index'); 
Route::get('/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{five}', 'ErrorController@index'); 
Route::get('/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{five}/{six}', 'ErrorController@index'); 
Route::get('/{one}/{two}/{three}/{four}/{five}/{six}/{seven}', 'ErrorController@index');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good but not very practical. What you want is pass all your parameters as query string in your url. ie

```
/any?id=1&name=joe
```

and define your route like this

```
Route::get('/any',function(){
    return Request::all();
})//
```

output

```
{"id":"1","name":"joe"}
```